# Connecting from another instance on AWS via a port

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What is the best way to enable specific port access from one instance to another. 
It would be good to not have to authorize on a per IP basis, so that it could work even when instances are added or removed.

Answer (score 4):

To authorize instance 1 access to instance 2 on port P,

- create two security groups, S1 and S2 (replace with your own meaningful names)
- modify security group S2 so that it allows access from security group S1 on port P.
- start instance 1 with security group S1.
- start instance 2 with security group S2.

The instances can have multiple security groups if you need other access.